# Creating a semi-dynamically defined array

Tags: c++, templates

I have to create a class that uses an array. The array can have variable length that is defined (with an actual number) upon the object construction, meaning I know it's size at the compile time.

So, I tried to create a template where I could input the size and have the object be constructed with that size. This way I could still use arrays.

But this code doesn't compile.

use of class template requires template argument list

What am I doing wrong?

h:

```
#pragma once

class BinaryMemoryReader;

template <int bytesPerValue>
class ChunkBlockChannel
{
public:
    std::map<unsigned int, unsigned char[bytesPerValue * 1024]> cbcLayer;
    std::map<unsigned int, unsigned char[bytesPerValue]> jj;

    void read(BinaryMemoryReader &reader);

    ChunkBlockChannel();
    ~ChunkBlockChannel();
};
```

cpp:

```
#include "ChunkBlockChannel.h"

#include "BinaryMemoryReader.h"

template <int bytesPerValue>
void ChunkBlockChannel::read(BinaryMemoryReader &reader) {

    for (int i = 0; i < 64; ++i) {
        bool flag;
        reader.read<bool>(flag);

        std::vector<unsigned char> cbcLayerData;
        std::vector<unsigned char> jjData;

        if (!flag) {
            unsigned char data[bytesPerValue * 1024];
            reader.readBytes(data, bytesPerValue * 1024);
            cbcLayer[i] = data;
        } else {
            unsigned char data[bytesPerValue];
            reader.readBytes(data, bytesPerValue);
            jj[i] = data;
        }
    }
}

template <int bytesPerValue>
ChunkBlockChannel::ChunkBlockChannel() {}

template <int bytesPerValue>
ChunkBlockChannel::~ChunkBlockChannel() {}
```

Comment: Why not using `std::array` instead of raw arrays?

Comment: To say that you have to know array size at object creation is NOT the same thing as having to know the array size at compile time...

Comment: I do know, I just don't want to create a bunch of different  classes that all differ by a single value. Probably should use the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe there is other but... you've forgotten the template argument in method definition.

I mean

```
template <int bytesPerValue>
void ChunkBlockChannel<bytesPerValue>::read(BinaryMemoryReader &reader) {
//      remember this ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

and

```
template <int bytesPerValue>
ChunkBlockChannel<bytesPerValue>::ChunkBlockChannel() {}
//      and this ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

and

```
template <int bytesPerValue>
ChunkBlockChannel<bytesPerValue>::~ChunkBlockChannel() {}
//      and this ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```